# How to throw exception based on feign.Response?

Tags: java, response, spring-cloud-feign, feign

I have a Feign client with a method returning the `feign.Response` class. When another service throws an exception, `feign` puts an exception message on response body and puts status, but my service does not throw an exception. Can I throw an exception based on what I received in response like when I use `ResponseEntity`.

**Feign client**

```
@FeignClient(name = "ms-filestorage")
@RequestMapping(value = "/files", produces = "application/json")
public interface FileStorageApi {

    @GetMapping(value = "/{id}")
    Response getFileById(@PathVariable String id);
}
```

**Usage of client**

```
@Override
public Response getFileFromStorage(String fileId) {
    Response fileStorageResponse = fileStorageApi.getFileById(fileId);

    // NOW I USE THIS WAY FOR CHECKING RESPONSE BUT IT DOESN'T LOOK GOOD
    //if (fileStorageResponse.status() != HttpStatus.OK.value()) {
    //    throw new OsagoServiceException();
    //}
    return fileStorageResponse;
}
```

Comment: Looks OK to me.

Comment: You can use feign Error Decoder and check responce status and throw exceptions.
If you want to handle OK responce, then use Feign Decoder. You can create custom class and add your own impletation.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, if a Feign client call receives an error response from the API it is calling, it throws a `FeignException`.

This can be caught in a try / catch block (or a Feign `ErrorDecoder` if you want to be more sophisticated, but that's another post).

However, this is not the case if you map the error response into a `Feign.Response` return type - see [this Github issue](https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign/issues/585).

Instead of returning `Feign.Response` from `getFileFromStorage()`, you should create a custom Java object to hold the response, and you will then have access to the `FeignException` which you can handle as you wish.

Note that if you don't need access to the data that is returned from the API you are calling, changing the return type to `void` will also resolve this issue.